# ¿Cómo añadir una etiqueta a un <h5> para dividir un párrafo en dos mediante JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

¡Hola muy buenas!

Dispongo de un `h5` con la clase `AñadirClaseParaSaltoDeLineaEnTextoPortada` cuyo contenido es:

> "Mudanzas Euro-Sur somos una empresa de mudanzas que contamos con más
>   de 30 años de experiencia en el sector y que ofrecemos diferentes
>   servicios y traslados como por ejemplo el de archivos confidenciales,
>   material de laboratorio, guardamuebles además de realizar mudanzas de
>   viviendas tanto nacionales como internacionales. Con Mudanzas Euro-Sur
>   disfrutará de nuestra amplia profesionalidad para hacer su mudanza
>   desde su domicilio a cualquier lugar del mundo.Nos caracterizamos por
>   contar con un gran servicio, rápido, eficiente y de calidad, es para
>   nosotros muy importante satisfacer las necesidades de nuestros
>   clientes con la mayor calidad y el mejor trato posible puesto que un
>   cliente satisfecho es un motivo más para seguir realizando nuestro
>   trabajo."

Mediante `javascript` le he tenido que agregar esa clase porqué estoy trabajando con WordPress y la página principal está montada con secciones y todo el rollo, total, que no puedo editar la página normalmente y modificar el `html`.

¿Qué necesito? Básicamente necesito separar todo ese código en dos párrafos, es decir, en dos `h5` para que se vea todo ese texto con un salto de línea.

He pensado en meter una etiqueta `span` justamente en:

> "Con Mudanzas Euro-Sur disfrutará de nuestra amplia profesionalidad
>   para hacer su mudanza desde su domicilio a cualquier lugar del
>   mundo.Nos caracterizamos por contar con un gran servicio, rápido,
>   eficiente y de calidad, es para nosotros muy importante satisfacer las
>   necesidades de nuestros clientes con la mayor calidad y el mejor trato
>   posible puesto que un cliente satisfecho es un motivo más para seguir
>   realizando nuestro trabajo."

¿Cómo lo podría hacer mediante `javascript`?
Si existe una manera más fácil, estoy abierto a sugerencias.

PD: He intentado meter un `br` mediante CSS pero los únicos pseudoselectores que existen son el de seleccionar la primera línea, todo el elemento o la primera letra.

IMAGEN:

[image: Imagen]
¡Un saludo de antemano y muchas gracias!

Comment: usa document.documentElement.querySelector('.AñadirClaseParaSaltoDeLineaEnTextoPortada '); para recoger el texto en el js, después modificado como si fuera una String y luego usar innerHtml para volverlo a pegar al html

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Al final ha sido tan fácil como recuperarme la clase `AnadirIdParaSaltoDeLineaEnTextoPortada`, guardármela en una variable, crearme otra variable para meter los dos `h5` que comentaba para tener dos párrafos y simplemente lo he añadido con un `innerHTML`.

Aquí dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve:

```
var texto = document.getElementsByClassName ("description");
texto[0].setAttribute('class', 'AnadirIdParaSaltoDeLineaEnTextoPortada');

var textH5 = document.documentElement.querySelector('.AnadirIdParaSaltoDeLineaEnTextoPortada');

var textH5_text = "<br><h5 class='AnadirIdParaSaltoDeLineaEnTextoPortada' id='primerH5'>Mudanzas Euro-Sur somos una empresa de mudanzas que contamos con más de 30 años de experiencia en el sector y que ofrecemos diferentes servicios y traslados como por ejemplo el de archivos confidenciales, material de laboratorio, guardamuebles además de realizar mudanzas de viviendas tanto nacionales como internacionales></h5>" + "<br><h5 class='AnadirIdParaSaltoDeLineaEnTextoPortada' id='segundoH5'>Con Mudanzas Euro-Sur disfrutará de nuestra amplia profesionalidad para hacer su mudanza desde su domicilio a cualquier lugar del mundo.Nos caracterizamos por contar con un gran servicio, rápido, eficiente y de calidad, es para nosotros muy importante satisfacer las necesidades de nuestros clientes con la mayor calidad y el mejor trato posible puesto que un cliente satisfecho es un motivo más para seguir realizando nuestro trabajo.</h5>"

textH5.innerHTML = textH5_text;
```

¡Un saludo!